# Problema con renovación de certificado Let's Encypt

Tags: ubuntu, certificado-ssl, letsencrypt

No se si a alguien que use  Let's Encrypt le pasó pero ayer recibí un email solicitando renovación del certificado ya que deshabilitan la validación TLS-SNI-01. Hace un par de meses instalé el certificado y había puesto renovación automática, entiendo que esto ahora no tiene nada que ver pero, alguien tiene idea de que debo hacer a grandes rasgos?
Estoy usando certbot 0.26.1, Apache2 y Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: A mi me pasa similar, también tengo el cron, pero aún así no se renueva, es decir, genera el certificado y ya, pero, tal parece que en el CPanel el certificado no cambia, es decir: El certificado se renueva en el servidor. Pero en el CPanel hay que ingresar nuevamente las credenciales de forma manual. Es el costo de tener ssl gratuito

Comment: Let's Encrypt no está para hacer las cosas más difíciles, es todo lo contrario. Si crees que no es así, seguramente estás haciendo algo mal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Debes actualizar Certbot a la versión 0.28 o superior.

Si estás con Ubuntu 16.04, haciendo un `sudo apt upgrade` debería bastarte para actualizar el cliente. Tras esto comprueba con `certbot --version` que tienes la versión adecuada y para quedarte tranquilo haz un `sudo certbot renew --dry-run` para simular una actualización de certificados.

Fuentes:

- https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-stop-using-tls-sni-01-with-certbot/83210
- Mis servidores, que también usan Ubuntu 16.04 y han sido actualizados con estos pasos.

**Nota**: Descubrí hace tiempo que Nginx no recarga los certificados y hay que reiniciar el servicio cada cierto tiempo con una entrada en cron como

```
05 3     * * *  service nginx restart 2>&1
```

para que éste actualice los certificados activos.